# Which package did install a file?

Tags: 14.04, cuda

I'm trying to remove cuda6.5 from my computer. There is no installed package with "cuda" in its name.

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep cuda
```

outputs nothing

but ldconfig shows these libraries.
`ldconfig -p | grep cuda
    libicudata.so.52 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.52
    libicudata.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so
    libcuda.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
    libcuda.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
    libcuda.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
    libcuda.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so`

I don't know which package installed them.

`dpkg -S` does not find anything either.

```
dpkg -S /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
```

`apt-file search /libcuda.so` output is

> ```
> libcuda1-304: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
> libcuda1-304: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
> libcuda1-304: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.304.117
> libcuda1-304: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.304.125
> libcuda1-304: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
> libcuda1-304: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
> libcuda1-304: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.304.117
> libcuda1-304: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.304.125
> libcuda1-304-updates: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
> libcuda1-304-updates: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
> libcuda1-304-updates: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.304.117
> libcuda1-304-updates: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.304.125
> libcuda1-304-updates: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
> libcuda1-304-updates: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
> libcuda1-304-updates: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.304.117
> libcuda1-304-updates: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.304.125
> libcuda1-331: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
> libcuda1-331: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
> libcuda1-331: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.331.113
> libcuda1-331: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.331.38
> libcuda1-331: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
> libcuda1-331: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
> libcuda1-331: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.331.113
> libcuda1-331: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.331.38
> libcuda1-331-updates: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
> libcuda1-331-updates: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
> libcuda1-331-updates: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.331.113
> libcuda1-331-updates: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.331.38
> libcuda1-331-updates: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
> libcuda1-331-updates: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
> libcuda1-331-updates: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.331.113
> libcuda1-331-updates: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.331.38
> ```

Comment: Relevant: https://superuser.com/questions/10997/find-what-package-a-file-belongs-to-in-ubuntu-debian

Comment: You may have installed those files outside of apt, such as compiled something ?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-file search /libcuda.so`

Comment: Have you update the ld.so.cache ? running `sudo ldconfig`. Are those libcuda.so  file like `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1` really present on the filesystem  ?

Comment: They are present

Answer (score 0):

According to packages.ubuntu.com, this file is found in the following packages in Trusty:

> libcuda1-304, libcuda1-304-updates, libcuda1-331, libcuda1-331-updates

To do a search like this, go to http://packages.ubuntu.com and go down to "Search the contents of packages".

Note: the packages can change with different versions of Ubuntu, so make sure to select the correct Ubuntu version.

Comment: none of these is installed! what should I do?